# Evaluating a complex contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula, winding-number

Evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{z}{e^z-1}dz$$

For:

[image: gamma contour]

Unfortunately, I'm really clueless... I've thought using Cauchy Theorem with Winding numbers, but there are 2 poles and one removable singularity inside the region, what can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the removable singularity. So, by the residue theorem, your integral is equal to$$2\pi i\left(1\times\operatorname{res}_{2\pi i}\left(\frac z{e^z-1}\right)+2\times\operatorname{res}_{-2\pi i}\left(\frac z{e^z-1}\right)\right),$$where the numbers $1$ and $2$ are the winding numbers of your loop with respect to $2\pi i$ and to $-2\pi i$ respectively. Now, you can compute the residues using the formula$$\operatorname{res}_a\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right)=\frac{f(a)}{g'(a)}.$$